# Which upcoming conventions, conferences, and events in 2012 should we attend?

Tags: discussion, events

StackExchange has indicated that [it's willing to send community leaders to relevant community events](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/) if it's particularly relevant (and if we agree to drop some UX.SE stickers here and there ;)).

> Depending on the circumstances and location, we can also sponsor community leaders to attend an event on behalf of their site. We will subsidize your costs to attend, within reason, and provide you with a bunch of swag to use as an ice-breaker when introducing yourself. No, really!

It's our responsibility to approach them and take advantage of this offer - they're not experts in UX so they don't know which events are important to us and which we'd like to attend.

So which are they? Let's make a comprehensive list of upcoming events this year that you think someone from the UX community could attend. Try to list why the event is relevant and if you've been there, perhaps share your experiences.

Comment: Here's a list of [upcoming UX conferences](http://finduxevents.com/ux-calendar/ux-conferences/2012/)

Comment: What happens next...?

Answer (score 5):

I'm already booked to attend [UXLondon](http://2012.uxlondon.com/) in April (18-20th) this year with a fantastic [list of speakers](http://2012.uxlondon.com/speakers/) and would be proud to be a UX.SE ambassador and write up on it.

With the likes of Bill Buxton, Jared Spool, and Luke Wroblewski whose name and writings are linked on posts here almost daily, and topics covering many of the questions we encounter here as well as many more that I'm sure we *will* be receiving in time, this has to be a serious contender.

Having those, and all the other 'names', it's obviously going to attract some UX fans - I feel this is an event not to be missed from the perspective of putting ux.se out there in the UX community.

Comment: btw - I also attend a number of smaller (generally free) events in the Cambridge,UK area on topics of UX, usability, mobile, interaction design and the like. It would be easy to give out cards or promote ux.se at these events, if some generic biz cards or similar were available.

Comment: I'm sure @Jin can hook you up!

Comment: @RogerAttrill I plan to make generic site cards for our SE sites very soon.

Comment: coolarooni! (yep - I said that out loud!)

Comment: @Jin This conference is coming up in a couple of weeks. I also nudged KatyHW on this question: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/576/has-anybody-been-to-ux-london#comment1088_576 . Re the actual question above (' *we can also sponsor community leaders to attend* ') - am assuming nothing's happening wrt this particular event as it's all gone waaay too quiet... :-)

Answer (score 5):

### [An Event Apart](http://aneventapart.com/)

- Seattle: April 2-4,
- Boston: June 18-20,
- Austin: July 9-11,
- Washington DC: Aug 6-8.

Comment: AEA is especially relevant because it's one of the biggest, most covered and attended events all year. If we could get at least one UX member to each of these it could potentially help boost our membership significantly!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to **Google I/O** again this year. It takes place [from June 27 to June 29 at the Moscone Center in San Francisco](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/11/google-io-2012-extended-to-three-days.html).

On the surface it doesn't sound like it would have much relevance to user experience design, but there's a surprising number of topics Googlers talk about that are directly related. Now that Google+ is out and Google have introduced their visual redesign, I'm also excited to hear anything their teams have to say about that entire process.

And there's also the fact that I think UXers should have a certain understanding of code and modern Web technologies as it affects what interaction possibilities are available.

Answer (score 3):

The Association for Computing Machinery's [CHI 2012](http://chi2012.acm.org/) (Computer Human Interaction) this year focuses on Experience.

- Austin Texas
- May 5-10

Chief sponsors include Google and Microsoft. SIGCHI is more specifically an HCI conference but this year's focus is on User Experience so it would be good to attend.

Answer (score 2):

UIE is doing [UX Immersion Conference 2012 – Agile/Mobile](http://www.uie.com/brainsparks/2012/01/24/why-agile-and-mobile-design-is-the-focus-at-ux-immersion/) from April 23-25 in Portland Oregon.

Jared Spool says:

> We’ve carefully designed the UX Immersion program to get you completely up to speed on where we are in these new worlds. You’ll learn the latest techniques for dealing with a UX process in an Agile environment. You’ll discover what it takes to build usable, useful, and delightful mobile apps that work within the ever-changing standards.
>
> We’ve assembled an amazing team of leading-edge thinkers on these new forces. These folks have been pioneering these areas. They are the thought-leaders that everyone goes to for the tough problems. And, importantly, they are excellent teachers who can make a day of this material really fun and engaging

Comment: My product is super relevant for the theme of this conference, so I'm thinking of going if I can scrape together some cash. Stupid living-in-Europe-$800-flights...

Answer (score 1):

## UXcamp Ottawa

### Ottawa, Ontario, Canada

13-14 October 2012 (a Saturday and Sunday)

http://uxcampottawa.org/

> The first day of UXcamp will consist of structured session featuring
>   fantastic speakers from Canada and the US. Depending on the final
>   schedule, the afternoon is expected to be an open, participatory event
>   whose content is provided entirely by the event participants.
>
> On Sunday, UXcamp will host a full-day ‘Design Jam’ where the
>   attendees, speakers and volunteers will be split into teams and will
>   work on a specific design problem. After lunch, the teams will present
>   their final designs and our judges will awards prizes to our winners.

I'll be there!

**EDIT**: [Tickets are available now](http://uxcampottawa.org/tickets/).